# How to tell if you have BeautifulSoup tag or text object?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Suppose I have a tag object and I navigate to the previous sibling:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup("...", "html.parser")
    anchor1 = soup.find_all("a")[0]
    prev = anchor1.previous_sibling
```

What's the best way to determine if `prev` is a tag object or a text object?

Is checking `type(prev)` against `"bs4.element.Tag"` and `"bs4.element.NavigableString"` the preferred way to do this?

Comment: For example you can do `isinstance(soup.a.previous_sibling, NavigableString)` which returns `True` if previous sibling is a text. Or `soup.a.find_previous_sibling()` will always try to find a `Tag`. `soup.a.find_previous_sibling(text=True)` will try to find first text previous sibling (ignoring Tags between)

Comment: I often forget to add bs4 by itself to imports, so I'd also say `if isinstance(prev, NavigableString)` is a handy way. (When I'm confident there are only tags and NavigableStrings, I just use something like `if not prev.name` but that can be a risky habit)